# How do I expand my mind a little bit, man?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

[image: Man, you're like a slave to society, man]

What do I need to do to expand my mind a little bit?

Comment: is that from the game?

Comment: @paralytic yep, that's part of the game.

Comment: Just to clarify something, the War Hippy Fatigues do NOT count until the war quest has begun. Anyone who has ascended can tell you that.
If you withdraw the war hippy fatigues from storage and wear it, you'll still be told you're a slave to society.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be wearing the Filthy Hippy Disguise, which is a set with the filthy knitted dread sack and the filthy corduroys. Both of these items are dropped by hippies in the Hippy Camp.

Another option is the War Hippy Fatigues (reinforced beaded headband, bullet-proof corduroys, and round purple sunglasses), but you will typically have the equipment for the Filthy Hippy Disguise by the time you have the capability of getting the War Hippy Fatigues.

Note that if you clear the infestation at the Hippy Store (a side-quest during the Island War main quest), you will be able to access the Hippy Store without having to wear a specific set (and you'll gain ~4000 meat every day by visiting).

Comment: I think any hippy outfit works, there is at least one more.